# Good way to query server object being in local cache

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

So I have a database that store users. When someone log on my website, it stores in apollo cache a user as **currentUser**. And I only store his id.

So I made a query to get a user by passing his id :

```
query {
  user(id: "id") {
    id
    username
    avatar
  }
}
```

But everytime I wanna get data for that user I need to make two query (the first one locally to get back his id from the cache and a second one to the server).

```
const GET_CURRENT_USER = gql`
  query getCurrentUser {
    currentUser @client
  }
`;

const GET_USER_DATA = gql`
  query getUser($id: String!) {
    user(id: $id) {
      id
      username
      avatar
    }
  }
`;


const currentUserData = useQuery(GET_CURRENT_USER);
const { currentUser } = currentUserData.data;

const { data, loading } = useQuery(GET_USER_DATA, {
  variables: { id: currentUser.id },
  fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network"
});
```

Is here a way that I can reduce that to only one query (the one to the server) ?

Comment: why arent you saving it in memory of your app

Comment: @elvis_ferns I'm caching it, but the data that it stored on the server can be changed by two applications. So I cannot just trust the cached data, that's why I need to query to the server. And I don't really like to query first on my cache and to my server, and would like to have only one query (if possible)

Comment: if its real time data why use apollo cache to save it. Just save id in memory

Comment: @elvis_ferns Because with all my data stored in apollo cache, I can trust a single store. And I like the fact that I access data locally and remotely with a similar way (query, mutation, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` value stored in the cache can be read using `readQuery`, you can store it in other global store/state, f.e. redux.

If you're using apollo cache as global store then using queries is a natural part of this process.

Using `readQuery` you can read the value without querying (but doing the same). One query 'saved' ;)

Deeper integration (additional query, local resolver) is not a good thing - creating unnecessary dependencies.

If you want to reuse this "unneccessary query" extract it to some module or create a **custom hook** (`id` read/used/saved once during initialization) - probably the best solution for this scenario.

**Another solutions**:

- make login process providing user data - for some inspiration take a look at [apollo-universal-starter-kit](https://github.com/sysgears/apollo-universal-starter-kit/blob/906cc92eacff97e21202ed62a8bfe42012d946b1/modules/user/client-react/graphql/Login.graphql) - but this is for initial data only (login/avatar changing during session??) - further user querying still needs an `id` parameter - it must be stored and read somewhere in the app.
- make `id` optional parameter (for `getUser` query - if you can change backend) - if not provided then return data for current user (`id` read from session/token)